# Email Validation with HTML5 Required Attribute plus Regular Expression Pattern

Tags: regex, html, validation

I'm using the native HTML5 validation for an "email" field and it works fine! However, I would like to increase it to a specific case, where I do not want to accept emails with "free" domains (gmail, hotmail, etc).

I did the regular expression and tested it and it worked correctly (Here you can do the test: https://regex101.com/r/wBt3YN/1). But when applying to the pattern of the email field, nothing happens.

How to proceed?

**Some strings:**

maykel@gmail.com -> Can't allow

maykel@marfin.com -> Can allow

maykel@outlook.com -> Can't allow

**Regex Pattern**

```
^([\w-.]+@(?!gmail\.com)(?!yahoo\.com)(?!hotmail\.com)(?!mail\.com)(?!live\.com)(?!aol\.com)(?!outlook\.com)(?!bol\.com)(?!msn\.com)(?!ymail\.com)([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$
```

**My form**

```
<form>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="email">Email Corporativo</label>
        <input 
          type="email" 
          name="email" 
          id="email" 
          value="" 
          pattern="^([\w-.]+@(?!gmail\.com)(?!yahoo\.com)(?!hotmail\.com)(?!mail\.com)(?!live\.com)(?!aol\.com)(?!outlook\.com)(?!bol\.com)(?!msn\.com)(?!ymail\.com)([\w-]+.)+[\w-]{2,4})?$" 
          title="Utilize seu email corporativo" 
          placeholder="" 
          required
        >
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
```

Comment: Did you test your assertions about how the form is being processed using web client dev tools?

Comment: @jdv how can i do that?

Comment: Most browsers have a "developer" mode. For example, Chrome on Windows uses F12. Your browser/platform may be different, but simply searching "browser developer mode" will get you all the info you need.

Comment: i got it on my chrome, but i dont know how can it help me.

Comment: Where can i see some useful information about that on my console?

Comment: The idea is that you can inspect forms and other page internals in real-time, or by adding breakpoints. You want to test your assertions. For example, you can change the pattern in the devtools UI and see if a simplified pattern works. Is that code even being reached? What I'm driving at is that you are in the best position to debug your own code.

Comment: BTW, you also don't say clearly what the actual results are that you get. That is "nothing happens" isn't very clear. Are you saying the pattern matches too aggressively? Not at all? Explain what results you get.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code where I do not allow yahoo & hotmail. However, e-mail validation is a very delicate thing.

```html
<form>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="email">Email Corporativo</label>
        <input 
          type="email" 
          name="email" 
          id="email" 
          value="" 
          pattern="^[^@]+@(?!(yahoo|hotmail))[^@]+\.[a-z]{2,}$" 
          title="Utilize seu email corporativo" 
          placeholder="" 
          required
        >
  </div>
  <input type="submit" value="ENVIAR">
</form>
```